# Power BI Survey Monkey Intergration

Tags: api, powerbi, surveymonkey

I am trying to establish an api connection between power bi and survey monkey apply.  Im trying to do this via Survey Monkey's app directory page (https://www.surveymonkey.com/apps/qL5WNYqHKY6GGeqJjDA1YA_3D_3D/details/).  However when I go to this page and log in, I keep getting a password incorrect error message, but when I use the same password logging into survey monkey apply directly, I can log in no problem.  Why is the app directory page not allowing me to log in and make the api connection between the two apps?